# i want to find max node in linked list by recursion algorithrm but my code has problem

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, linked-list, max

if I enter amount of linked list is 3 : x1 = 3, x2= 1, x3=2 that print : 2 1 3(it really true) but max=2, I could not find bug, This is my code:

```
int max(Node l){
    int max = 0;
    if(l == null) return 0;
    else
    {
        if(l.data > max){
            max = l.data;
            l = l.next;
        }                 
        else return max(l.next);
    }
    return max;
}
int max(){
    return max(head);
}
```

Comment: Why the recursion?

Comment: because my teacher require me use recuresion

Comment: Can you please explain your problem. I didn't get this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong, since you always return the value of the first element (since `l.data > max` will always be `true`, since `max` is always `0` at this point).

The correct way to think of finding the max element recursively is as follows:

The max element is the max of the first element and the max of the rest of the list.

i.e.

```
max(l) is the max of l.data and max(l.next)
```

So your method should look like this:

```
int max(Node l)
{
    if(l == null) 
        return 0;
    else {
        int tailMax = max(l.next);
        return tailMax > l.data ? tailMax : l.data;
    }
}

int max(){
    return max(head);
}
```

Comment: sorry, i don't understand sysnax (? and :) i'm learning java maybe you wirting another language

Comment: @KhoaVõĐức it's the ternary conditional operator. Equivalent to `if (tailMax > l.data) {return tailMax;} else {return l.data;}`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative by writing an explicit [tail-recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) function `max`

```
int max(Node l, int maximum)
{
    if(l == null) 
        return maximum;
    else {
        return max(l.next, l.data > maximum? l.data: maximum);
    }
}

int max(){
    return max(head, 0);//something small...
}
```